# Windows 10: Run certain applications at a different scaling level

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10, resolution, scaling, high-dpi

I bought a 24" 4k/UltraHD monitor a while ago and used it with Windows 8.1 at 200% scaling. With most modern applications I use, the scaling worked fine and the crisp text was a blessing for my eyes.
Unfortunately I had to ditch my old-old secondary monitor (19") because it could only scale at 200% which was absolutely ridiculous and unusable.

Now I upgraded to Windows 10 a few weeks ago and heard that it supported per-Monitor display scaling. So I hooked up my "old" 24" 1200p monitor and set it up accordingly: 4k monitor @ 200% scaling and 1200p monitor @ 100% scaling.

It works, but only so-so:

- Some applications re-scale when I drag them to the other monitor, but become blurry. Readable, but blurry. All Office 2013 programs, both Firefox and Chrome and Sublime Text do this, for instance.
- Some applications, which work fine at 200% scaling (e.g. the latest VMware Workstation 12 or VLC player), do not rescale at all and are still ridiculously large at the secondary monitor.
- Funnily enough, those applications that have no and/or crap scaling (e.g. iTunes) look fine on the secondary monitor, just like they'd look with 100% scaling. (But look like crap on the 4k monitor...)

The one and only program I have yet found to scale correctly on both 100% and 200%, is the Windows Explorer.

Long story short, until MS fixes this, I'd like to start a few applications at 100% scaling and drag them to my secondary screen just to get some peripheral information.

For this, I thought I'd just make a couple of shortcuts to the respective programs and select "Disable Display Scaling On High DPI Settings" in the properties. Unfortunately, this changes absolutely nothing.

Is there another way to achieve my goal? Or have my plans of multi-monitors with different PPIs failed yet again?

Thank you!

Comment: This problem might never be fixed, simply because people who wrote old versions of applications assumed the world would always have regular, not 4k screens.